# How can I emit a (loud) 25 kHz sound wave from a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: audio, pwm

I am attempting to emit a 25 kHz ultrasonic square sound wave from my Raspberry Pi. I have used two different kinds of ultrasonic speakers:

https://www.amazon.com/gp/prod uct/B00M2GHG66/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

and

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07RW7ZNB4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RW7ZNB4)

I use the standard GPIO library with pulse width modulation, set to 25000 Hz, 50% duty (I have also tried 90% duty). The speakers were plugged directly into the Pi on ground and the PWM output pin 12.

My result: Output is very quiet and distorted. It sounds like someone is screaming.

How can I get a louder, cleaner tone at 25 kHz?

Comment: Can you hear 25kHz? Are you sure you are not hearing the harmonics (e.g. 12.5kHz, 6.25kHz, etc.)?

Comment: @Rohat Kılıç With 25KHz carrier frequency, 12.5kHz, 6.25kHz, etc. envelops are not harmonics, but modulation frequencies

Comment: you need to use an amplifier

Comment: How are  you measuring the output? Ultrasonic, by definition, is above the range of (human) hearing.

Comment: Do you understand what _ultrasonic_ means?

Comment: You need more voltage (easily done with a BJT class A amplifier) and more current (not that much, as ultrasonic speakers are more like capacitors, but still need current). I would go with an unbiased class B BJT push pull after the voltage amplifier - the more you distort, the better the dog will like it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GPIO pins aren't designed to drive high power loads, just provide data signals.  You need some kind of amplifier - even a simple MOSFET would help.  There will be plenty of examples of GPIO pins driving MOSFETS on the web.

If you can hear it, it's not 25kHz.  A very small number of people might hear it as an extremely high pitched whistle, but most people can't hear 25kHz at all, no matter how loud.  You might be hearing vibrations at some fraction of 25kHz, though.

Comment: Thank you Simon B.  This answer was very helpful to me.  To clear things up, when I use a different 25khz tone generator (whose hardware is a mystery to me), I do not necessarily hear it but I do experience aural pain when it is turned on.

Comment: what is _aural pain_?

Comment: @mguima aural = related to ears. Tdoggo's ears hurt

Comment: ***IF YOU EXPERIENCE AURAL PAIN, STOP IMMEDIATELY!*** You might ruin your earing! Powerful ultrabass are reportedly mostly harmless, but powerful ultrasounds are very dangerous.